# Android status bar scrolling up with coordinator layout, leaving status icons overlapping toolbar title

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I am experiencing an issue when using Coordinator Layout that contains an AppBarLayout (holding a ToolBar and a TabLayout) and a ViewPager (holding fragments) as children. I want the topbar to be hidden when scrolling down, and revealed when scrolling back up. However when I scroll down, the status bar scrolls up as well, leaving the top bar just below the status icons, being overlapped by them.

I tried adding android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to both the AppBarLayout and the ViewPager but nothing changed.

Below the code used and snapshots showing the two states:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: Status Bar without scroll applied]

[image: Status Bar with scroll applied]

Comment: I had this exact same problem, and i was able to solve it, but I don't have the code with me! A few possibilities: a) `fitsSystemWindows="true"` on your `AppBarLayout`, b) Add a `contentScrim` to your `AppBarLayout` or `Toolbar` (`app:contentScrim="@color/primaryDark"`), or c) try a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` instead of `AppBarLayout`, but don't give it collapsing scroll flags. Hope one of those helps!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Review the theme for the activity, if the theme is like @style/AppTheme.NoActionBar or one theme without ActionBar, try putting a color, you must have a style(v21) something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>    
</style>
```

change it for :

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is ok if you don't want to use a navigation drawer for example to show with a transparent status bar...

Comment: @CaptRisky, what to do if I also want to use navigation drawer?

Comment: @frozzyk I'm using material drawer (mike penz) and I had to stop it scrolling up, haven't found a solution. Pretty sure the OP is using the same library as you can see the elevation of the appBar in the status bar area.

Comment: should to use "?attr/colorPrimaryDark" to support multi-theme app.

Comment: @CaptRisky did you ever find a solution? I have 2 Activities, one with a navigation drawer, one without - the one with works as expected when scrolling (toolbar disappears), however the second one doesn't do under status bar properly, and I can't use `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>` because of the navigation drawer.