# Android - Toolbar goes above Statusbar on Listview scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to hide the toolbar when a listview is scrolled, using Coordinator Layout. I've used `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` on my toolbar, and `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` in my listview.

The toolbar hides correctly when I scroll down my listview, but it goes 'above' the statusbar. In web development terminology, it looks like the 'Z-Index' of the toolbar is higher than the statusbar. This is how it looks -

[image]
[image: Toolbar above Statusbar]

Here is my `activity_main.xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my `fragment_main.xml` code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE: I've posted my answer below! Check for the accepted answer.**

Comment: Scrolling abilities aren't supported under the ListView for the new CoordinatorLayout. You've got to use a RecyclerView instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally fixed this. If anyone else if stuck here, this is how I fixed it. No need to change your layouts to Recyclerview and all! Here are the steps.

1) Set the fitsSystemWindows to false for the CoordinatorLayout.

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

2) Now, my status bar turned white. To fix this, add the following lines to your onCreate method in MainActivity.java

```
Window window = getWindow();

// clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

// add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

// finally change the color
window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

Voila! Now everything works perfect.

Here is my activity_main.xml contents, in case I missed something.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: I think this may be an easier answer to what you're trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989984/android-status-bar-scrolling-up-with-coordinator-layout-leaving-status-icons-ov

Comment: @Amit But this will only change the color of status bar to a solid one. How to have gradient colors in the status bar

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have `AppBarlayout` and `toolbar` layout if you do not want a toolbar that expands and contracts? basically that AppBarlayout is used when one wants it to be expanding and contracting and it used with a `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` so chances are the issue is coming up from there, they are not compatible, you could use a `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`in place of the `listview` and the `viewpager` has the attribute `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` which triggers the `appbarlayout` to start listening for scroll inputs, I archieve having a normal behaving toolbar by not having `AppBarlayout` but only `toolbar` so you could remove the AppBarlayout, looking at things it is not really needed, since you happen to want it to expand and contract below is a sample of how your code should look like

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">




    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/scrollableview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <!-- Your content, maybe a ListView? -->
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/fabAddItem"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/google_lightblue"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

    <aubry.chromio.com.dressup.view.CollapsingTitleLayout
    android:id="@+id/backdrop_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
    app:expandedTextSize="40dp"
    app:expandedMargin="16dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</aubry.chromio.com.dressup.view.CollapsingTitleLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and here is my CollapingsTitleLayout

```
 import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.TypedArray;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.text.TextPaint;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
    import android.util.TypedValue;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;

    import aubry.chromio.com.dressup.R;


 public class CollapsingTitleLayout extends FrameLayout {

// Pre-JB-MR2 doesn't support HW accelerated canvas scaled text so we will workaround it
// by using our own texture
private static final boolean USE_SCALING_TEXTURE = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18;

private static final boolean DEBUG_DRAW = false;
private static final Paint DEBUG_DRAW_PAINT;
static {
    DEBUG_DRAW_PAINT = DEBUG_DRAW ? new Paint() : null;
    if (DEBUG_DRAW_PAINT != null) {
        DEBUG_DRAW_PAINT.setAntiAlias(true);
        DEBUG_DRAW_PAINT.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    }
}

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private View mDummyView;

private float mScrollOffset;

private final Rect mToolbarContentBounds;

private float mExpandedMarginLeft;
private float mExpandedMarginRight;
private float mExpandedMarginBottom;

private int mRequestedExpandedTitleTextSize;
private int mExpandedTitleTextSize;
private int mCollapsedTitleTextSize;

private float mExpandedTop;
private float mCollapsedTop;

private String mTitle;
private String mTitleToDraw;
private boolean mUseTexture;
private Bitmap mExpandedTitleTexture;

private float mTextLeft;
private float mTextRight;
private float mTextTop;

private float mScale;

private final TextPaint mTextPaint;
private Paint mTexturePaint;

private Interpolator mTextSizeInterpolator;

public CollapsingTitleLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CollapsingTitleLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CollapsingTitleLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    mTextPaint = new TextPaint();
    mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CollapsingTitleLayout);

    mExpandedMarginLeft = mExpandedMarginRight = mExpandedMarginBottom =
            a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CollapsingTitleLayout_expandedMargin, 0);

    final boolean isRtl = ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(this)
            == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;
    if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.CollapsingTitleLayout_expandedMarginStart)) {
        final int marginStart = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.styleable.CollapsingTitleLayout_expandedMarginStart, 0);
        if (isRtl) {
            mExpandedMarginRight = marginStart;
        } else {
            mExpandedMarginLeft = marginStart;
        }
    }
    if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.CollapsingTitleLayout_expandedMarginEnd)) {
        final int marginEnd = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.styleable.CollapsingTitleLayout_expandedMarginEnd, 0);
        if (isRtl) {
            mExpandedMarginLeft = marginEnd;
        } else {
            mExpandedMarginRight = marginEnd;
        }
    }
    if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.CollapsingTitleLayout_expandedMarginBottom)) {
        mExpandedMarginBottom = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.styleable.CollapsingTitleLayout_expandedMarginBottom, 0);
    }

    final int tp = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CollapsingTitleLayout_android_textAppearance,
            android.R.style.TextAppearance);
    setTextAppearance(tp);

    if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.CollapsingTitleLayout_collapsedTextSize)) {
        mCollapsedTitleTextSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.styleable.CollapsingTitleLayout_collapsedTextSize, 0);
    }

    mRequestedExpandedTitleTextSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.styleable.CollapsingTitleLayout_expandedTextSize, mCollapsedTitleTextSize);

    final int interpolatorId = a
            .getResourceId(R.styleable.CollapsingTitleLayout_textSizeInterpolator,
                    android.R.anim.accelerate_interpolator);
    mTextSizeInterpolator = AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(context, interpolatorId);

    a.recycle();

    mToolbarContentBounds = new Rect();

    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

public void setTextAppearance(int resId) {
    TypedArray atp = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(resId,
            R.styleable.CollapsingTextAppearance);
    mTextPaint.setColor(atp.getColor(
            R.styleable.CollapsingTextAppearance_android_textColor, Color.WHITE));
    mCollapsedTitleTextSize = atp.getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.styleable.CollapsingTextAppearance_android_textSize, 0);
    atp.recycle();

    recalculate();
}

@Override
public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    super.addView(child, index, params);

    if (child instanceof Toolbar) {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) child;
        mDummyView = new View(getContext());
        mToolbar.addView(mDummyView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }
}

/**
 * Set the value indicating the current scroll value. This decides how much of the
 * background will be displayed, as well as the title metrics/positioning.
 *
 * A value of {@code 0.0} indicates that the layout is fully expanded.
 * A value of {@code 1.0} indicates that the layout is fully collapsed.
 */
public void setScrollOffset(float offset) {
    if (offset != mScrollOffset) {
        mScrollOffset = offset;
        calculateOffsets();
    }
}

private void calculateOffsets() {
    final float offset = mScrollOffset;
    final float textSizeOffset = mTextSizeInterpolator != null
            ? mTextSizeInterpolator.getInterpolation(mScrollOffset)
            : offset;

    mTextLeft = interpolate(mExpandedMarginLeft, mToolbarContentBounds.left, offset);
    mTextTop = interpolate(mExpandedTop, mCollapsedTop, offset);
    mTextRight = interpolate(getWidth() - mExpandedMarginRight, mToolbarContentBounds.right, offset);

    setInterpolatedTextSize(
            interpolate(mExpandedTitleTextSize, mCollapsedTitleTextSize, textSizeOffset));

    ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
}

private void calculateTextBounds() {
    final DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    // We then calculate the collapsed text size, using the same logic
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(mCollapsedTitleTextSize);
    float textHeight = mTextPaint.descent() - mTextPaint.ascent();
    float textOffset = (textHeight / 2) - mTextPaint.descent();
    mCollapsedTop = mToolbarContentBounds.centerY() + textOffset;

    // First, let's calculate the expanded text size so that it fit within the bounds
    // We make sure this value is at least our minimum text size
    mExpandedTitleTextSize = (int) Math.max(mCollapsedTitleTextSize,
            getSingleLineTextSize(mTitle, mTextPaint,
                    getWidth() - mExpandedMarginLeft -mExpandedMarginRight, 0f,
                    mRequestedExpandedTitleTextSize, 0.5f, metrics));
    mExpandedTop = getHeight() - mExpandedMarginBottom;

    // The bounds have changed so we need to clear the texture
    clearTexture();
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    final int saveCount = canvas.save();

    final int toolbarHeight = mToolbar.getHeight();
    canvas.clipRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(),
            interpolate(canvas.getHeight(), toolbarHeight, mScrollOffset));

    // Now call super and let it draw the background, etc
    super.draw(canvas);

    if (mTitleToDraw != null) {
        float x = mTextLeft;
        float y = mTextTop;

        final float ascent = mTextPaint.ascent() * mScale;
        final float descent = mTextPaint.descent() * mScale;
        final float h = descent - ascent;

        if (DEBUG_DRAW) {
            // Just a debug tool, which drawn a Magneta rect in the text bounds
            canvas.drawRect(mTextLeft,
                    y - h + descent,
                    mTextRight,
                    y + descent,
                    DEBUG_DRAW_PAINT);
        }

        if (mUseTexture) {
            y = y - h + descent;
        }

        if (mScale != 1f) {
            canvas.scale(mScale, mScale, x, y);
        }

        if (mUseTexture && mExpandedTitleTexture != null) {
            // If we should use a texture, draw it instead of text
            canvas.drawBitmap(mExpandedTitleTexture, x, y, mTexturePaint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawText(mTitleToDraw, x, y, mTextPaint);
        }
    }

    canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
}

private void setInterpolatedTextSize(final float textSize) {
    if (mTitle == null) return;

    if (isClose(textSize, mCollapsedTitleTextSize) || isClose(textSize, mExpandedTitleTextSize)
            || mTitleToDraw == null) {
        // If the text size is 'close' to being a decimal, then we use this as a sync-point.
        // We disable our manual scaling and set the paint's text size.
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
        mScale = 1f;

        // We also use this as an opportunity to ellipsize the string
        final CharSequence title = TextUtils.ellipsize(mTitle, mTextPaint,
                mTextRight - mTextLeft,
                TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        if (title != mTitleToDraw) {
            // If the title has changed, turn it into a string
            mTitleToDraw = title.toString();
        }

        if (USE_SCALING_TEXTURE && isClose(textSize, mExpandedTitleTextSize)) {
            ensureExpandedTexture();
        }
        mUseTexture = false;
    } else {
        // We're not close to a decimal so use our canvas scaling method
        if (mExpandedTitleTexture != null) {
            mScale = textSize / mExpandedTitleTextSize;
        } else {
            mScale = textSize / mTextPaint.getTextSize();
        }

        mUseTexture = USE_SCALING_TEXTURE;
    }

    ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
}

private void ensureExpandedTexture() {
    if (mExpandedTitleTexture != null) return;

    int w = (int) (getWidth() - mExpandedMarginLeft - mExpandedMarginRight);
    int h = (int) (mTextPaint.descent() - mTextPaint.ascent());

    mExpandedTitleTexture = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(mExpandedTitleTexture);
    c.drawText(mTitleToDraw, 0, h - mTextPaint.descent(), mTextPaint);

    if (mTexturePaint == null) {
        // Make sure we have a paint
        mTexturePaint = new Paint();
        mTexturePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTexturePaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    mToolbarContentBounds.left = mDummyView.getLeft();
    mToolbarContentBounds.top = mDummyView.getTop();
    mToolbarContentBounds.right = mDummyView.getRight();
    mToolbarContentBounds.bottom = mDummyView.getBottom();

    if (changed && mTitle != null) {
        // If we've changed and we have a title, re-calculate everything!
        recalculate();
    }
}

private void recalculate() {
    if (getHeight() > 0) {
        calculateTextBounds();
        calculateOffsets();
    }
}

/**
 * Set the title to display
 *
 * @param title
 */
public void setTitle(String title) {
    if (title == null || !title.equals(mTitle)) {
        mTitle = title;

        clearTexture();

        if (getHeight() > 0) {
            // If we've already been laid out, calculate everything now otherwise we'll wait
            // until a layout
            recalculate();
        }
    }
}

private void clearTexture() {
    if (mExpandedTitleTexture != null) {
        mExpandedTitleTexture.recycle();
        mExpandedTitleTexture = null;
    }
}

/**
 * Recursive binary search to find the best size for the text
 *
 * Adapted from https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview
 */
private static float getSingleLineTextSize(String text, TextPaint paint, float targetWidth,
                                           float low, float high, float precision, DisplayMetrics metrics) {
    final float mid = (low + high) / 2.0f;

    paint.setTextSize(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, mid, metrics));
    final float maxLineWidth = paint.measureText(text);

    if ((high - low) < precision) {
        return low;
    } else if (maxLineWidth > targetWidth) {
        return getSingleLineTextSize(text, paint, targetWidth, low, mid, precision, metrics);
    } else if (maxLineWidth < targetWidth) {
        return getSingleLineTextSize(text, paint, targetWidth, mid, high, precision, metrics);
    } else {
        return mid;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns true if {@code value} is 'close' to it's closest decimal value. Close is currently
 * defined as it's difference being < 0.01.
 */
private static boolean isClose(float value, float targetValue) {
    return Math.abs(value - targetValue) < 0.01f;
}

/**
 * Interpolate between {@code startValue} and {@code endValue}, using {@code progress}.
 */
private static float interpolate(float startValue, float endValue, float progress) {
    return startValue + ((endValue - startValue) * progress);
}
```

}

Comment: I actually want the toolbar to contract when the listview is scrolled. But I want to to behave properly - that is go behind the statusbar when it contracts.

Comment: then your approach is very bad, I am updating my answer, am giving you a sample of how it should be like, but you will have to  replace the `listview` with a `recyclerview`

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this with native components? I'm assuming aubry.chromio.com.dressup.view.CollapsingTitleLayout is an external component?

Comment: I have added the CollapsingTitileLayout

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I'll try making the changes

Comment: the android design library provides in built attributes in its app bar layout for expanding and contracting a toolbar on scroll events.